Custom Caret Positioning in React Input Field Lags Behind Characters
Question:
I'm trying to create a custom blinking caret for an input field in a React application. I've hidden the default caret and positioned a custom caret based on the text width up to the caret position. However, I'm encountering an issue where the custom caret lags behind the characters as the input increases in length.
I've set up a hidden measuring element styled to match the input field to calculate the caret's position, but the custom caret is not aligning accurately with the text.
Code Sandbox Link :Sandbox
The Issue:
The custom caret initially looks correct but lags behind the text as more characters are typed. top and left position should be sync as like normal cursor
The left position seems to be incorrect, especially as the input value grows.
What I've Tried:
Ensuring the hidden measuring element exactly matches the input's styling.
Adding padding and border width to the calculated left position.
Adjusting the caret's top position based on the input's padding.
Expected Behavior:
The custom caret should align precisely with the default caret position, maintaining correct placement relative to the text at all times.
Actual Behavior:
The custom caret starts off correctly but progressively lags behind the text, not keeping up with the typed characters.

Could you make your code into a runnable snippet, ie show enough HTML to demonstrate the problem and use the <> icon in the editor.

@AHaworth I have attached code Sandbox link

Relevant code still belongs directly into your question (reason: once your external source changes or disappears, this question will lose context for future readers.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#return_value: "Properties other than width and height are relative to the top-left of the viewport." - but your caret element is not positioned in relation to the viewport; it is positioned in relation to .input-container
